# PySpark, Win10 - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: pyspark

I previously had PySpark installed as a Python package I installed through pip, I uninstalled it recently with a clean version of Python and downloaded the standalone version.

In my User variables I made a path with name: SPARK_HOME

with a value of: C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

In System variables under Path I made an entry: C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin

[When I run pyspark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm0x9.png)

I can not run spark-shell either. Any ideas?

Comment: Firstly, SPARK_HOME should be without bin  C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\

You add \bin in system variables.

Did you add JDK as JAVA_HOME? If yes, did you set JAVA_HOME in hadoop_env.cmd?

Comment: huh, removing bin from SPARK_HOME and JAVA_HOME fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SPARK_HOME** should be without `bin` folder. Hence,

Set `SPARK_HOME` to `C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\`

Comment: On my word, that took a day and an evening to figure out. Judging by the number of people having issues, Spark and other library creators really ought to provide *clear* installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

Window users have to download a compatible winutils exe version and save it in your Spark's bin folder.

Find the compatible Hadoop distribution, download and save it in your Spark folder.

e.g. Download "https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe" and save it in your "C:\spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin"

Different winutils version could be found in this link.
https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

Comment: A link to solution is good but make sure that your answer provide more details

Comment: Thanks. Edited as you suggested. I don't know why someone downvoted it. It is a tried and true solution for me and my friends.