# System cannot find the specified route on creating SparkSession with PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, intellij-idea, pyspark

I'm trying to learn Spark together with Python on a Win10 virtual machine. For that, I'm trying to read data from a CSV file, with PySpark, but stops a the following:

[image]

> C:\Users\israel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> C:/Users/israel/Desktop/airbnb_python/src/main/python/spark_python/airbnb.py
>
> hello world1
>
> System cannot find the specified route

I have read [How to link PyCharm with PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685905/how-to-link-pycharm-with-pyspark) , [PySpark, Win10 - The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726043/pyspark-win10-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified) ,
[The system cannot find the path specified error while running pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49340941/the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error-while-running-pyspark) , [PySpark - The system cannot find the path specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788384/pyspark-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified)  but haven't found luck implementing the solutions.

I'm using IntelliJ, python 3.7. This is the run configuration.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using IntelliJ, python 3.7. The code is as follows

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *


if __name__ == "__main__":

    print("hello world1")

    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("spark_python") \
        .master("local") \
        .getOrCreate()

    print("hello world2")

    path = "C:\\Users\\israel\\Desktop\\data\\listings.csv"

    df = spark.read\
        .format("csv")\
        .option("header", "true")\
        .option("inferSchema", "true")\
        .load(path)

    df.show()

    spark.stop()
```

It seems like the error is in the SparkSession, but I don't see how the announced error is related to that line. It is worth to mention that the execution never ends, I have to manually stop the execution to rerun it.  Can anyone give me lights on what I'm doing wrong?. Please

Comment: Have you checked the paths `SPARK_HOME`, `HADOOP_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`? Are they all correct?

Comment: Yes, they are as the last image

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this is not the best solution, but one approach would be to launch your python interpreter directly from pyspark binary.

This can be located in:
    $SPARK_HOME\bin\pyspark

Additionally, if you modify your environment variables when any terminals are active the variables are not refreshed till the next launch. This applies to Pycharm too. If you haven't tried, a restart of pycharm may also help.

Answer (score 0):

## **If the error message is written with `sys.stderr`**

The answers I provide here are not for real questions,

but I noticed what you said: **but I don't see how the announced error is related to that line...**

So I want to provide you with debugging to find the location of the code that generated this message.

According to the image of your `airhnb`(the first one), the error message `El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada`.
It looks like this was written by `sys.stderr`

So my method is to redirect `sys.stderr`, like the following:

```
import sys


def the_process():
    ...
    sys.stderr.write('error message')


class RedirectStdErr:
    def write(self, msg: str):
        if msg == 'error message':
            set_debug_point_at_here = 1
        original.write(msg)
        original.flush()


original = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = RedirectStdErr()

the_process()
```

[image]

As long as you set the breakpoint on the `set_debug_point_at_here = 1`, then you can know where the real place to call this code is.